# List<String> @Test removing null from last index

Tags: java, list, assertion

I've made this method :

```
  public static List<String> getPascalTriangle(int size) {
        if(size <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size of a triangle cannot be negative number or equal to 0");
        }
        List<String> triangle = new ArrayList<>();
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
            int r = i + 1;
            for (int j = size - i; j > 0; j--) {
                row.append(String.format("%2s", ""));
            }
            int num = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (j > 0) {
                    num = num * (r - j) / j;
                }
                row.append(String.format("%4d", num));
            }
            triangle.add(row.toString());
            row.setLength(0);
        }
        triangle.add(row.toString());
        return triangle;
    }
```

Now I want to test it. I've create simple @Test

```
   public void shouldReturnCorrectPascalTriangle() {
        List<String> expected = new ArrayList<>();
        expected.add("                 1");
        expected.add("               1   1");
        expected.add("             1   2   1");
        expected.add("           1   3   3   1");
        expected.add("         1   4   6   4   1");
        expected.add("       1   5  10  10   5   1");
        expected.add("     1   6  15  20  15   6   1");
        expected.add("   1   7  21  35  35  21   7   1" + ", ");

        assertEquals(expected, PascalTriangle.getPascalTriangle(7));
    }
```

My only issue here is that my original List is adding something like additional index at the end. It looks like ", ". I cannot remove it. Tried to use getList.remove(index) - it didn't help.
[image: screenshot from diffmerge file]
Any thoughs how can I remove this bloody thing and successfully finish this task ?
Also I was thinking is there any clever way or dedicated way to test Illigall Argument Exception from the @Test level ? Eg. I am removing the statment If(size <= 0) from my method but I am checking it in Test.

Comment: To answer the latter question, you can have a `@Test` that uses a `try`/`catch` block to make sure an exception is thrown (call the offending code, then `fail()`. If it doesn't jump to the `catch` block then it didn't throw the exception it was supposed to)

Comment: Just remove `triangle.add(row.toString());` at the end of the code, right before the `return`?  That seems to be what is adding the extra value in the `List`.

Comment: May I recommend storing the triangle as a list of lists (outer list for the rows, inner list for the values)? This will solve most of your problems, and it would much easier to work with. At most you would need to create a simple print function for the triangle.

Comment: @Nexevis , Thanks it worked out !

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy  Try/Catch +1 from me for your assistance =)

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two problems here:
First the problem you mentioned. You have to remove `triangle.add(row.toString());` just before `return triangle`. Now you add empty string at the end of your program.
Second thing is your `assertEquals`. You try to assert two different list references. It will return false. You can fix this by checking contents of your lists

```
assertEquals(expected.toString(), PascalTriangle.getPascalTriangle(7).toString());
```